# How to deal with ESOL questions/answers?

Tags: discussion

How to deal with an answer that is presented like someone's used a foreign-to-english dictionary on each word, but the whole content is obscured?

For example [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/45873/19705)
User seems to be making an effort to help, but the finer points are lost in translation.

[Semi-Related meta question](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237/) but that assumes there's something salvageable in the question/answer, that needs to be dug out of the wording.

Answer (score 4):

If the OP doesn't look like she's going to fix the answer ==> and there's a useful answer embedded somewhere in there ==> I'd go ahead and edit it for clarity and grammar.

If it's a right holy mess of incomprehensible blather, I'd flag it for removal.

Answer (score 2):

Well, basically all you can do is ask for a clarification and vote/flag it if necessary.

You can also suggest they also post the content in their native language **as well** as in English (not in its stead). If someone improves it with a translation, thats good.

But you'd have to vote/what not on the languages you understand.